# When dragging a mesh onto a rig, the rigging menu with "with automatic weights" option won't appear

Tags: rigging

I'm using the basic meta rig produced by using the Rigging plugin. I aligned the rig's bones to my model and when i parent the go to rig it the menu with options like "with automatic weights won't appear"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to apply the rigging in edit mode or object mode? The rig with automatic weights only works correctly in pose mode. Also, you can not select "with automatic weights" in object or edit mode by going to the object tab, because it will not parent the bones correctly. I make this mistake often.